# Resizing a Usercontrol to the Width of the Container

Tags: user-controls, vb6, containers

I am authoring a new UserControl and I want to know when the container control resizes, and when does it set the width of the UserControl to be that of the container?

I though I might be able to set the Alignable property and set this to be AlignTop but this didn't work when the container was a TabControl because it moved the control over the tabs.

I don't believe that the AmbientChanged event fires on a parent resize?

Is there some way of detecting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no ambient changes when the parent size changes. As `Align` won't help, you'll need to use the resize code of the form or tabstrib to resize the user control.

Alternatively, you can align your user control in a picture box but that will still need to be resized by the container in code.

**Here be dragons!**

Another, far more fragile option is to get a reference to the container control and assign it to a `VBControlExtender` variable with `WithEvents`. This will then allow you to react to the `Resize` event (if it has one) and call `Extender.Move`. Note that you must add code to the parent form to clear this on close otherwise you'll have a circular reference and the form won't shut down correctly.